# MySQL crashes on Open Cursor

Tags: mysql

I am having problems with a stored procedure.
Why does the code crash on the "OPEN ltLCur" statement (w/o "select" statement)?

Without the first "select concat" debug statement, the code will fail on the next line: OPEN ltLCur.  The debug socket connection with NetBeans terminates.
With the "select" statement the code continues and returns a result set from the "select concat" statement.

I tried adding:

```
DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET done = 1;
```

to no avail.

If I perform, in phpMyAdmin:

```
SELECT a, b FROM zcs WHERE zp = 290 LIMIT 1;
```

This does return data.  So, I know it does not return an empty set.

Ideas?

See code below.

MySQL Server version: 5.6.19

```
CREATE PROCEDURE abc(IN zc INT, IN rm INT)
BEGIN

    DECLARE ltVal  VARCHAR(255);
    DECLARE lgVal VARCHAR(255);

    DECLARE ltLCur CURSOR FOR
    SELECT a, b FROM zcs WHERE zp = zc LIMIT 1;

    OPEN ltLCur;

    FETCH ltLCur INTO aVal, bVal;

    SELECT * from evtCl
    WHERE v_zC in (SELECT z FROM zcs
         WHERE l1
         BETWEEN aVal  bVal);

END
```

Comment: You declare the cursor named `lLCur`, but you open `ltLCur`. Is the typo in the real code or a copying error here?

Comment: Typo, sorry, corrected.

Comment: Are you actually doing something with the cursor after opening it?  That isn't shown in your code.  Cursors in stored procedures are intended to be iterated with `FETCH NEXT FROM cursorname INTO var1, var2;` inside a loop.

Comment: Yes, the next statement in the complete code is a FETCH.  But the code never gets there.  I only posted enough text to get to the crash.  Ok, I'll post the rest for completeness.